# Changing styles/css in Angular2 with JS changes styles for a moment and then reverts back to its previous styles

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

So I'm using the following JS to change styles to some elements in Angular 2. When I load the view the height is set for a moment to maxHeight = 100, but after a few millisecs it reverts back to the styles on the stylesheets. Anyone has any clues what might be happening can styles be changed directly with JS in angular?

```
  let projectMatchers = document.getElementsByClassName("th-project-matcher");
        let rowMatchers = document.getElementsByClassName("th-row-matcher");

        let maxHeight = 100;
        rowMatchers[i].style.height = maxHeight + "px";
        projectMatchers[i].style.height = maxHeight + "px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think the styles I was applying with javscript where overwritten by [change events of angular 2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html), so I used ngStyle to apply styles directly to my div and it works without problems:

```
    <div class="my-class" [ngStyle]="matchHeight(i)"></div>
```

this is matchHeight():

```
public matchHeight(index: number): string {
    return {
        height: "250px",
    };
}
```